# nginx proxy_pass resolver not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, resolver

I have setup a nginx (1.9.5) as a proxy for few tomcat servers. I am pointing to these servers through a route53 domain name using proxy_pass directive.  Somehow the "resolver" directive which resolves the domain name works once during startup. But it does not re-resolve although "resolver" directive is setup.

```
   server {

        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl on;
        resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=10s;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ssl-bundle3.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/chewie.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 180m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";

        location / {
                resolver_timeout 30s;
                resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=10s;
                set $target "http://abctest.hello.world:80";
                proxy_pass $target;
                proxy_cache_bypass true;
                    proxy_no_cache true;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

                    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

            }
    }
```

Comment: using nginx version 1.9.5.

Comment: you can modify your *location / {* section as follows:
`location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  }`

hint: are you using DH params with 2048bit? You can update them, so you are able to achieve A+ ranking with ssllabs.com

Comment: @semm0 - The reverse proxy setup works fine. The domain name abctest.hello.world is also resolved during nginx startup. But it does not resolve again after startup although resolver direct is specified.